# MongoDB Realm convert BJSON to JSON

Tags: json, mongodb-realm

I am using MongoDB Realm Webhooks to allow for my react app to fetch data from my MongoDB Database. Everything works fine, however the data that I receive is not raw JSON, in the sense that every integer field in the object has an additional property which shows its data type. To better clarify this, I will show an example of the data that is returned:

```
stats: {
draws: {$numberInt: "1"}
games: {$numberInt: "271"}
goals: {$numberInt: "417"}
losses: {$numberInt: "23"}
}
```

Is there a way where I am able to parse the data so it can be formatted without the datatype? For example:

```
stats: {
draws: 1,
games: 271,
goals: 417,
losses: 23,
}
```

This would improve code readability for my frontend. I've tried to flatten the object manually using an object flatten function, but what I am dealing with is a large nested object, so it is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try `BSON.Binary.fromText` or similar functions. There's not a lot of documentation of the BSON utilities